# if ... then statement in Vagrantfile showing error "syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting `end'

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I am trying to setup hadoop cluster locally on three VMs. I have successfully setup my VMs. I have also installed hadoop on the master node. But, everytime I run vagrant provision, it downloads hadoop all over again which is time taking. I want to check if hadoop is already installed and skip the code that downloads hadoop if it is already installed.

Here is my code. /home/vagrant/hadoop is the location of hadoop.

```
      # Download and extract Hadoop on master node (i.e node1)      
      if node.vm.hostname == "node1"  
        # Check if Hadoop is already installed so it wont install every time you run vagrant provision
        if [ ! -d "/home/vagrant/hadoop" ]; then
          node.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
            wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.3.4/hadoop-3.3.4.tar.gz
            tar -xvzf hadoop-3.3.4.tar.gz
            mv hadoop-3.3.4 hadoop
          SHELL
        fi
      fi
```

This is the error I am getting.

`unexpected end-of-input, expecting` end'`

I changed the `fi` to `end` and I got the error below.

`syntax error, unexpected` end', expecting end-of-input

Comment: Your `if` uses Shell / bash Syntax. In the Vagrantfile however, you are writing Ruby. See [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-if+Expression) for details about Ruby's `if` syntax.

Comment: With that being said, the `if` probably needs to be executed on the host as part of the shell provision. Maybe just put it into the `SHELL` delimiter?

Comment: Or use Ansible to do idempotent operations such as file management. You could also look at Apache Bigtop and Ambari

Comment: Yes, the first suggestion works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're blurring the line between Ruby (Vagrant) and shell (host):

```
if node.vm.hostname == "node1"  
  # Check if Hadoop is already installed so it wont install every time you run vagrant provision
  node.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    if [ ! -d "/home/vagrant/hadoop" ]; then
      wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.3.4/hadoop-3.3.4.tar.gz
      tar -xvzf hadoop-3.3.4.tar.gz
      mv hadoop-3.3.4 hadoop
    fi
  SHELL
end
```

While the syntax of Ruby might, at least superficially, resemble the shell, it is quite different.

Remember, Ruby, running on your host machine, cannot test for directories that may or may not exist inside the VM. That's something you'll have to do with the shell, so it goes inside the shell command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @tadman. That solves it. I was blurring Ruby and Shell.